# How to get start and end of ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a pandas Series containing groups of numbers and nans, and I want to get the start and end of each group.  The following code does this:

```
def get_ranges(d):
    results = []
    start = None
    for i in range(len(d) - 1):
        if start is None and not np.isnan(d.ix[i]):
            start = d.index[i]
        if start is not None and np.isnan(d.ix[i + 1]):
            results.append((start, d.index[i]))
            start = None
    if start is not None:
        results.append((start, d.index[i]))
    return pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['start', 'end'])
```

E.g.:

```
In [24]: d = pd.Series([0, 1, 4, 2, nan, nan, nan, 4, 2, nan, 10, nan])

In[25]: get_ranges(d)
Out[25]: 
   start  end
0      0    3
1      7    8
2     10   10

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

But it seems like this is something that pandas should be able to do quite easily, possibly using `groupby`.  Is there some built in method of getting these groups that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it has a more convenient way to do that, followings are what I'm using:

#### Get the index of those have numbers but not nan

```
In [134]: s = d.dropna().index.to_series()

In [135]: s
Out[135]: 
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
7      7
8      8
10    10
dtype: int64
```

#### Get start and end by

```
In [136]: start = s[s.diff(1) != 1].reset_index(drop=True)

In [137]: end = s[s.diff(-1) != -1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Then you can construct what you want by

```
In [138]: pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'end': end}, columns=['start', 'end'])
Out[138]: 
   start  end
0      0    3
1      7    8
2     10   10

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isnull()` and `cumsum()` to create the groupby keys:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan
d = pd.Series([0, 1, 4, 2, nan, nan, nan, 4, 2, nan, 10, nan])

mask = d.isnull()
index = mask.cumsum()
mask = ~mask

d[mask].groupby(index[mask]).agg(
{"start":lambda s:s.index[0],
 "end":lambda s:s.index[-1]}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
   start  end
0      0    3
1      7    8
2     10   10
```